# CSS3, WebKit Transition Order? How to queue to the transitions?

Tags: html, webkit, css

I have the following:

```
-webkit-transition-property: top, bottom, z-index;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

Problem is I don't want the z-index to transition until after top & bottom are done.

Is there a way to tell Webkit transition to transition top/bottom and then when done, do z-index instantly or with the duration, either way?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to specify a delay on the z-index transition:

```
-webkit-transition-property: top, bottom, z-index;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, .5s;
```

Comment: Ah shoot that's great. I got it hacked together earlier using keyframes. This is far more elegant. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

And for your info, in javascript, you can also listen on the `webkitTransitionEnd` event and modify the z-index when this event is fired.

This event have two useful properties :

- propertyName : the name of the property involved in the transistion
- elapsedTime :  time elapsed during the transistion