# CSS Transition addition

Tags: css, transition

I stumbled upon a strange CSS effect on **Chrome (Doesn't happen on Firefox**).

I need to use a transition on more than 90% of my website elements, so I basicly added a transition to everything with the `*` CSS selector.

But it creates a weird delay when there are encapsulated elements, which happens a lot and is really annoying.

Is there any way to solve this other than putting the transition on every single element, and not globally ?

Thanks.

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

p:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Test <span>test2</span></p>
```

*EDIT : I already know you can solve that by better targeting your elements, but I'm asking for a way without having to do that.*

Comment: That's interesting! Annoying but interesting!

Comment: @Zenoo No problem. Another similar question here might be helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069877/css-transitions-strange-unwanted-delay-in-webkit-browsers-chrome-and-safari

Comment: Well, this question tells me to avoid `*` and target my elements single-handedly. I hope someone will have another answer here, because it would take me a long time to do that :x

Answer (score 0):

Though this solution will go into the same direction as targeting every transitioned element, only the reverse way targetting every container element... Will propably get very messy as well. The initial problem is not solved, why there is a delay when the parent element has a transition, so first finish parent transitions then start child transitions... my try is just a work around so that you try to select all very last childrens and then disable transition on them, because they already have transition through their parents...

edit: you'd have to add all container elements to the second rule, maybe it helps

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

*:not(body):not(div) > * {
  transition: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Test <span>test2</span></p>

</div>
```

Comment: There would be way too many selectors to write down, I might aswell do it one by one :/